# How to map all routes into a subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a live Rails app. Now I would like to reroute all of them to a subdomain dev.mydomain.com.

For example, current path `mydomain.com/users/1` should become `dev.mydomain.com/users/1`. All the links in my pages should work also.

How should I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: the reason I want to do this is because I want to hide my app from visitors, and redirect them to a different landing page.

Comment: You are messing up the terms path and url. What you want try to archive ? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for , check out the :host parameter

Comment: Hi, the reason I want to do this is because I want to hide my app from visitors, and redirect them to a different landing page.

Comment: Are `dev.myomain.com` and `mydomain.com` separate rails apps? What's your deployment stack? (Apache, nginx, thin, webrick?).

Comment: No. They are in the same app. The app is in stealth mode and I want to have only my landing page exposed to visitors. `dev.mydomain.com` is to show the app to friends and invited visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

1. Create a file in your config/lib directory called subdomain.rb then add this to it

   ```
   class Subdomain
       def self.matches?(request)
           if request.subdomain == "www" || request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain.empty? || request.subdomain.nil?
               false
           else
               true
           end
       end
   end
   ```

Then in your routes.rb you can do this

```
    require 'subdomain'

    DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do

        constraints(Subdomain)  do
            constraints(:subdomain => 'dev') do
                resources :users
                root :to => "someother#page"
            end
        end

        root :to => "default#index"

        # and any other routes you would like to expose to www or no subdomain.
    end
```

To run my apps I tend to use [pow.cx](http://pow.cx/) and I would recommend the same.